# Incorrect whitespaces or list item size in Android SE app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Noticed that sometimes when there are 10+ answers to a question - some answers look like they have `\n\n...\n` line breaks in the end, so the body of the answer has incorrect height.

It probably has something to do with `ViewHolder` or adapter not setting correct row height. Although as far as I know, it should do this according to text amount/length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.0.84.

The issue was that the `WebView` was being recycled for the different answers while scrolling and there's apparently a well known issue with web views where their layout size doesn't shrink when their content shrinks.  This means that after enough scrolling, all answers would become the same height as the longest answer on the screen.

To address this, the web views will no longer be recycled and rather stored in a map based on their contents.  When an answer appears, it will either reuse the existing view for the given HTML or create and cache a new one.  This will fix the size issue, ensure smooth scrolling through previously loaded answers, and reduce the total number of loads while scrolling.